# Codenameone IOS build online errors

Tags: ios, codenameone

So I tested building my app using the Codenameone send to IOS debugger build. It worked perfectly, as far as the build goes, however I didn't add this to the build that worked:

ios.gplus.clientId = "helloworld"

So I added that to the build hints and now it errors out on the IOS debugger build. The error log doesn't appear to be very helpful.

Any insights as to why this broke the build would be appreciated.

Comment: I'll need a relatively recent link to the build error or a mirror of the file to provide you with an answer. I doubt that's the reason. I'm guessing you have a certificate/signing related issue

Comment: Hi Shai, thanks for the help, here is the link to the build error: https://codename-one.appspot.com/getData?m=result&i=5104676170366976&b=bf03a47a-303a-4e6c-9597-09e2622c21c7&n=error.txt

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for that, it seems to be a regression in a recent VM change we'll try to fix this for the upcoming update later this week.

Comment: Thank you Shai, do you have an estimate on when the update will happen?

Comment: The fix was committed by Steve so it should be up tomorrow

Comment: Awesome! Thank you.